# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest in static library crashes on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, static-libraries, objective-c-blocks

I am compiling a static library (FAT binary) that includes the following:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; // also tried [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        // CRASH BEFORE BLOCK EXECUTES
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        ...
```

The code in itself runs fine if compiled with the app on a device and the simulator but it crashes when used as a static library in another app ONLY on the simulator. The static library works fine on an iOS device. The crash is a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and by doing some logging, I narrowed it down to the `sendAsynchronousRequest`. The block does not get called.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods instead. I am still curious to know why it was crashing, please do comment if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are creating your own queue? Try using `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` as the queue

Comment: Hmm sorry then. The rest looks correct, must be an issue elsewhere. Maybe try using NSURLSession if you can and see if the issue goes away?

Comment: Just curious as to why not? NSURLSession seems to do networking stuff better than NSURLConnection in my experience

Comment: sorry ive been pulled away from this project to work on other stuff and recently got back to it. the reason is I have to support iOS 6, otherwise I would have used it.